# How to specify the login_url to login for django generic views

Tags: django

login_required decorator directly taking url from settings.LOGIN_URL.  In which how can i specify login url with parameter **login_url**. Is this possible to specify both **login_url** and TemplateView.as_view() in login_required decorator

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo_index.html'))
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`login_url`** argument in **`login_required`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo_index.html'),
        login_url='/custom/login/url/'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can take a look at django source code and the implementation of `login_required`:

```
def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
   ...
```

the first param is your view. And other 2 params you can input as it is. Like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo_index.html'), login_url='/your_url/login')),
]
```